# json_decode file_get_contents help

Tags: php, file-get-contents, json

```
<?php
$json = file_get_contents('http://tiny.cc/ttrhelp');

$obj = json_decode($json);
$example = $obj->rooms->displayName;
?>

Name: <?php echo $example; ?>
```

Trying to show the value for 'displayName'  but its not showing

Comment: i know when someone down-votes it sensually add an explanation ... it's a new user ...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Untested code:**

```
<?php
$json = file_get_contents('http://pub.tapulous.com/tapplications/coresocial/v1/chat/api/index.php?method=room_list');

$obj = json_decode($json);
foreach($obj->rooms as $room){
    $example = $room->displayName;
    echo $example;
}

?>
```

Answer (score 5):

You probably want `$obj->rooms[0]->displayName`.

[CodePad](http://codepad.viper-7.com/RHXpUE).

Answer (score 2):

`echo $obj->rooms[2]->displayName;`

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
echo $obj->rooms[0]->displayName;
```